# Output not generating results in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean, user-input

**Problem:** An application that lets you enter an employee's gross pay and bonus amount and calculates the amount of retirement contribution.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Boolean_Method_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        private const decimal CONTRIB_RATE = 0.05m;
    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // The InputIsValid method converts the user input and stores
        //// it in the arguments (passed by reference). If the conversion
        ///// is successful, the method returns true. Otherwise it returns
        //// false. 
        private bool InputIsValid(ref decimal pay, ref decimal bonus)
        {
            bool inputGood = false;
            if (decimal.TryParse(grossPayTextBox.Text, out pay))
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(bonusLabel.Text, out bonus))
                {
                    inputGood = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bonus amount is invalid.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gross pay is invalid.");
            }
            return inputGood;
        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal grossPay = 0m, bonus = 0m, contributions = 0m;
            if (InputIsValid(ref grossPay, ref bonus))
                {
                contributions = (grossPay + bonus) * CONTRIB_RATE;
                contributionLabel.Text = contributions.ToString("c");
            }

        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**This issue:** The code seems to be correct, however every time I input data and click on calculate I keep getting this message:  "Bonus amount is invalid". Is the code not properly written or what exactly is happening. Am I not inputting the right data?

Comment: I see you have formatted the contributions as currency for display. Is it possible that bonusLabel.Text is also formatted?

Comment: @mary it was actually that slight mistake. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the `bonusLabel.Text`.  I'm going to guess that `bonusLabel` is the label of your TextBox, and not the TextBox itself. Is the TextBox called `bonusTextBox`, perhaps?

```
...
if (decimal.TryParse(bonusTextBox.Text, out bonus))
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this. It definitely solve the problem! I got confused between the label and the textbox. Do you have any recommendations on any C# books for advanced study? @ pcdev

Answer (score 0):

its look like you are doing parsing wrong way or wrong field , i suggest you should do like this , attach keypress event on your textbox control and force user to enter only number

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
   string text = textBox1.Text;
   return !Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\d+\.?\d*$";
 }

 private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     decimal grossPay = decimal.Parse(grorssTextBox.text);
     decimal bonus = decimal.Parse(bonusTextBox.text);
     //rest of code 
 }
```

instead of key paress you can put the regular expression code in you validate function also and do validate full textbox input.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look over this version. Do you know any books you would recommend on advanced study for C# @ pranay rana

Comment: @ABerrio - i like jhon skeet book C# in depth and C# in nutshell...that two book i like most..and that is pure C# book nothing related to UI stuff